# What is the effect on performance using the extract(DATETIME) function in Oracle 11g if I am using it in where condition to compare against a value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using an SQL statement that goes like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE extract(month from dateColumn)=x and name='xyz';
```

The table can have any number of records. What kind of effect will this query have on performance?

Answer (score 1):

1. the function "extract" will run as many times as many rows you have in the table (ofcourse this has performance penalty)
2. in case you do not have a "function based index" on "dateColumn" Oracle will have to "full scan" "MyTable" each time you run the query.

In case you have an index on "name" and the query is expected to return 1-100 rows then you can ignore performance penalty (as it is very and very small).

Comment: What if I do not have an index on the column "name", but it returns 1-100 rows? Can I ignore the performance penalty in that case?

Comment: No, in this case "full table scan" will happen. Assume you have 1mln rows, Oracle will have to scan all 1 mln rows to "extract month" and compare to "x". In case your table has only 1-2 hundred of rows you can ignore this penalty.

Comment: Could you suggest any other better performing ways to extract month/year from Date?

Comment: Better??? You could use this:  to_char(dateColumn,'mm') to get month or to_char(dateColumn,'yyyy') to get year, but this is not better or worst - this is just another method.
As per my understanding your problem is not the "function" but how to avoid "full table scan" and get resultset efficient.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is right. I want to avoid any potential timeout errors as my query is part of a program that deals with web services. So, what I understand from your comment is that to_char and extract method will have a similar effect and in this case, a "full table scan" is unavoidable. Am I right?

Comment: No, to avoid full table scan you must create an index on "dateColumn" or "name"  or on both columns. (pay attention that for "dateColumn"  it should be so called "function based index")